# htaccess redirect non-www subfolder to www subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory

I would like to redirect

> example.com/subfolder

to

> [www.example.com/subfolder](http://www.example.com/subfolder)

using htaccess

This is what I tried, but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For a strange reason it is redirecting

> example.com/subfolder

to

> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Its generic. It rewrites everything. Even if you have aliases.

```
#Rewrite for non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want top redirect a `subfolder` only then URI matching regex should match only a subfolder. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder(?:/.*)?)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have tried all of these excerpts listed in the subfolder .htaccess file, in the root .htaccess file, in both subfolder and root .htaccess file, with no .htaccess redirect, and using php redirect, but they all bring me back to the root of the website.

Comment: @ShoreShotWeb: Open a new question with your problem and I will attend it.